# Schema package validate key is in a sets

Tags: python

I'm working with the [schema](https://github.com/keleshev/schema) library and I'm trying to figure out how validate that the keys on a dictionary are in a defined set.

```py
MY_SET = {"a", "b"}
MY_SCHEMA = Schema({"parentkey": {"KEY I WANT TO VALIDATE": {"key": str}})
```

I attempted it w/ `Use` but that does not appear to behave as expected.

```py
>>> v = Schema({"parentkey": {Use(lambda x: x in {"a", "b"}): {"key": str}})
>>> v.is_valid({"parentkey": {"a": {"key": "hello"}}})
True
>>> v.is_valid({"parentkey": {"c": {"key": "hello"}}})
True
```

This does not appear to be the correct use case for a `Hook` as that only fires when it finds a matching key.

Edit:

Basically what I want to test is that at least 1 key in a set of key's exists in the dictionary and each key has the same underlying data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the only way I can enforce this.

```py
def has_values(val):
    if len(val) == 0:
        raise SchemaError("values required")
    return val


sch = Schema(And(dict, Use(has_values), {Optional("a"): str, Optional("b") str})
```

This would guarantee that the key's have at least one of the desired values and no values outside those.